# What new features will be added to Scala 2.9?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I know parallel collections will become available.

What form will these take, and what else are we likely to see?

Comment: 2.9 is out now: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/9483

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For the full list, see: [Beyond 2.8 - A Roadmap](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7285)

The main thing seems to be parallel collections. They are drop-in replacement for the scala collections, but the methods are executed in parallel.

From the scala days presentation by Aleksandar Prokopec:

> Scala parallel collections that will
>   be introduced in 2.8 reimplement
>   standard collection operations while
>   keeping compatibility with existing
>   Scala collection framework. They also
>   introduce new operations
>   characteristic for parallel
>   algorithms, and a few contracts the
>   programmer should be aware of.

For a good video explanation of parallel collections, see [Scala Parallel Collections - Aleksandar Prokopec](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/140)

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at this: [Changes between Scala 2.8 and Scala 2.9](https://sites.google.com/site/scalatohoku/changes-and-improvements-on-scala-2-9)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.infoq.com/interviews/martin-odersky-scala-future

It's in Jan 2011 fairly recent. Might help you ^***_***^.

Comment: He does not say anything about 2.9 but that it should have been released two months ago.

Answer (score 3):

Official site: [Scala 2.9.0 RC1](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8976) (from 2011-03-25, scala-lang.org)