# Code Optimization with Scala

Tags: optimization, scala

What structures of Scala can be used more efficiently than in Java, to increase execution speed? I don't know if this is possible, but to clear my doubts :)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The scala @specialized annotation can generate multiple versions of a class, fine-tuned with specific primitive types. You can write all of that out in Java, but you probably don't want to.

Answer (score 6):

As of 2.9, the parallel collections library is slated to be part of the standard distribution.  This will allow extremely simple distribution of so-called "embarrassingly parallel" problems over multiple cores.  Doing so in Java takes considerably more effort.

As a general rule, Scala benchmarks range from moderately slower than Java to slightly faster, depending on the problem and coding techniques.

Comment: Parallel collections are planned for 2.9. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900879/what-new-features-will-be-added-to-scala-2-9/

Answer (score 6):

To expand on Ross's answer, you can use @specialized to generate specific versions of a collection. For instance, in Java you'd generally use [fastutil](http://fastutil.dsi.unimi.it/) or [Apache Primitives](http://commons.apache.org/primitives/) for collections of primitives. Scala's @specialized will generate these variants for you and hide them automatically like so:

```
class MyLinkedList[@specialized T] (args: T*) {
  // whatever it does
}
```

Other than that, actors make it easier to write concurrent applications. Coming up in 2.9 are parallel collections, which can apply higher-order functions in parallel across collections, speeding up any place you'd have the Scala equivalent of a Java loop (fold, foreach, etc). See [this ScalaDays talk](http://days2010.scala-lang.org/node/138/140) for the nitty-gritty on this.

Answer (score 2):

I'll refrain from speculation on how the resulting performance might differ from an equivalent Java construct, but Scala does [closure elimination](http://lamp.epfl.ch/~dragos/files/talk-hofs.pdf), which might make a measurable difference, modulo HotSpot tricks.

Also stay tuned for [Iulian's thesis](http://library.epfl.ch/en/theses/?nr=4820) which should be out soon and will provide a lot more information on the subject of Scala optimization.